# Visual Studio 2022 latest update changed outlining behavior

Tags: razor, updates, visual-studio-2022, outlining

The most recent updates to VS 2022 have broken my normal outlining. Working in Blazor Server (.razor pages), I used to be able to collapse code tag areas, and it would leave the first line intact with an ellipse. Now it is squashing the whole area, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]